# Failed to load library from git in androidStudio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm trying to `barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer` in my android project but it fail to load the lib and I can't figure out why... Any Idea?

Here's my config :
`build.gradle (:app)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.multimatum_team.multimatum"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.github.multimatum_team.multimatum.MultimatumTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
    testCoverage {
        jacocoVersion = "0.8.7"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include:["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    ....
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.4.0'
    testImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.1'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
    jacoco.includes = ["com.application.*"]
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }

    def fileFilter = [
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*Test*.*',
            'android/**/*.*',
            // Exclude Hilt generated classes
            '**/*Hilt*.*',
            'hilt_aggregated_deps/**',
            '**/*_Factory.class',
            '**/*_MembersInjector.class'
    ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.setFrom(files([mainSrc]))
    classDirectories.setFrom(files([debugTree]))

    executionData.setFrom(fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec',
            'outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*/coverage.ec'
    ]))
}

connectedCheck {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

`build.gradle (project`

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories{
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

error : "Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1."

I haven't found why I cannot load a library from github. Do I have to use something like jitpack?

I cannot use maven since the lib doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just link to code in github like that.  It needs to be packaged into a library and downloaded in compiled form.  You have to use maven or similar repository.  Gradle doesn't even know how to download source code from git for a dependency, it only expects packaged code.

I wouldn't use this library in any case.  It hasn't been updated in 3 years, and the first line of its readme is that its looking for a new maintainer.  And since it has no updates, it didn't find one.  I would be vary wary of some random library on github, and doubly wary of one that's not maintained.